# number theory problem finding triplets

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

Find number of triplets of positive integers satisfying

$2^a-5^b\cdot 7^c=1$

Given options are $0 , 1 , 2$ or infinite.

Comment: zero solution, take log on both sides

Comment: @Amruth A can you explain because taking log on LHS would not yield anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is even, then $2^a=(3-1)^a=1\bmod3$. Then we have $5^b7^c=0\bmod3$ which is impossible, so $a$ must be odd.

But if $2,2^2,2^3,2^4=2,4,3,1\bmod5$. We have $2^a=1+5^b7^c=1\bmod5$, so we must have $a$ a multiple of 4.

Contradiction. So there are no solutions.

Comment: Assuming by positive integers we don't include $0$. Otherwise we can have $(1,0,0)$ or $(3,0,1)$.

Comment: Has 0 ever been a positive integer!

Comment: I agree there are no solutions, but you made a mistake. 2^a may leave a remainder of 2 when divided by 3. The remainder is (-1)^a, not necessarily 1

Comment: @almagest I should've bettered worded it "assuming OP didn't mean natural numbers" :p

Comment: @Huang Not for even $a$. Of course it is possible for odd $a$, that is why we have to look mod 5 as well.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Sorry.